# Authentication in angular and bootstrap application

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I have a front end application made with Angular and a backend API made with laravel that the front end communicates with.

Now I'm in need of user authentication, registration, password reset and everything related. As I understand laravel already has built in software to provide this but is meant to be used with the front end provided by laravel.

My question is can it also be used as an authentication API by an external application - in my case my Angular front end application?

Also if it can then how are sessions managed? I imagine laravel keeps the session in a regular PHP session. If I visit the API from my browser then my browser will remember the session id in a cookie. But if I send my requests from Angular then how can Angular keep the session id?

Answer (score 0):

API's are stateless and don't use session. API uses Tokens. Use JWT to maintain authentication via API. A token generated after the first authentication and after that, each request via API will use that token. In angular "Satelizer" do for you.